# How to change Folder Icon in all Document Library

Tags: custom, custom-list, folder, file-icons

how could I change the Folder Icon in Sharepoint? Is something programmatically, on CSS or simply to change icon in the specific image folder?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find this file in all the web front end servers
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\itdl.png`

Replace this with your own image and your folder icon will get updated.

Please note this will effect at a farm level , so if you want to make it site collection specific , you need to use visual studio and create a custom feature to establish the same.

Comment: but be carefully, if you do this, the changes will be applied across all the sites in your server. If you would like to change folder's images for one site or site collection use additional page header delegate control and CSS.

Comment: Alexander, can you provide a detailed pointer?