# Assigning Icons to Content types

Tags: document-library, content-type, custom-list, file-icons

I have added a couple of content types that inherit from "folder" and some other from "item" (and each other, but they're not the issue).
How can I, **if** that's possible at all, set another icon for my content types other than the default folder icon?
I saw in another question( [How to change Folder Icon in all Document Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36863/how-to-change-folder-icon-in-all-document-library) ) that there was a way to change the folder icon on a farm level but since there are also others using the farm that's not an option for me.

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it out of the box.

Your best option is probably to create your own NewMenu control that loops the content types and adds them to the menu.

This should get you started:
http://paulliebrand.com/2008/07/14/customaction-newmenu-and-mysterious-blank-control/